# how to add profile photo uploader to a pre-existing form and database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Please, I'm new to php and I am trying to code a registration form where users can also upload their profile image. other parts of the form is working fine, just the upload aspect is giving me headache. I've searched many forums but none has given me the answer to my problem.

I'll post my previous code when my laptop is connected cos the server is really slow here.

I'll appreciate any help pls, and I'll like only the image name to be stored in the database, I don't need any other property of the image. And the image should be uploaded to a specific folder/directory. And the image name should be changed also, so its the new name that I would like to store in the database.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my script below:

```
<?php
//We check if the user is logged
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['passverif'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['avatar']))
{
    //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['passverif'] = stripslashes($_POST['passverif']);
        $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['avatar'] = stripslashes($_POST['avatar']);
    }
    //We check if the two passwords are identical
    if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passverif'])
    {
        //We check if the password has 6 or more characters
        if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=6)
        {
            //We check if the email form is valid
            if(preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\.?)*[a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@(([a-z0-9-_]+\.?)*[a-z0-9-_]+)\.[a-z]{2,}$#i',$_POST['email']))
            {
                //We protect the variables
                $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
                $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                $avatar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar']);
                //We check if there is no other user using the same username
                $dn = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as nb from users where username="'.$username.'"'));
                //We check if the username changed and if it is available
                if($dn['nb']==0 or $_POST['username']==$_SESSION['username'])
                {
                    //We edit the user informations
                    if(mysql_query('update users set username="'.$username.'", password="'.$password.'", email="'.$email.'", avatar="'.$avatar.'" where id="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']).'"'))
                    {
                        //We dont display the form
                        $form = false;
                        //We delete the old sessions so the user need to log again
                        unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']);
?>
<div class="message">Your were successfully Updated. You need to log again.<br />
<a href="connexion.php">Log in</a></div>
<?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Otherwise, we say that an error occured
                        $form = true;
                        $message = 'An error occurred while updating your informations.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Otherwise, we say the username is not available
                    $form = true;
                    $message = 'The username you want to use is not available, please choose another one.';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise, we say the email is not valid
                $form = true;
                $message = 'The email you entered is not valid.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Otherwise, we say the password is too short
            $form = true;
            $message = 'Your password must contain at least 6 characters.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Otherwise, we say the passwords are not identical
        $form = true;
        $message = 'The passwords you entered are not identical.';
    }
}
else
{
    $form = true;
}
if($form)
{
    //We display a message if necessary
    if(isset($message))
    {
        echo '<strong>'.$message.'</strong>';
    }
    //If the form has already been sent, we display the same values
    if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email']))
    {
        $pseudo = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passverif'])
        {
            $password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
        else
        {
            $password = '';
        }
        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        if(isset($avatar))
    {
        $avatar = htmlentities($_POST['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, we display the values of the database
        $dnn = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select username,password,email,avatar from users where username="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"'));
        $username = htmlentities($dnn['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $password = htmlentities($dnn['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $email = htmlentities($dnn['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $avatar = htmlentities($dnn['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
    //We display the form
?>


<div class="content">
<?php include('adverts.php'); ?>
<br />
<form action="edit_infos.php" method="post" class="message">
    <i><b>Edit your personal Info</b></i><br />
    <div class="center">
        <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password<span class="small">(6 characters min.)</span></label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" /><br />
        <label for="passverif">Password<span class="small">(verification)</span></label><input type="password" name="passverif" id="passverif" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" /><br />
        <label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /><br />
        <label for="avatar">Avatar<span class="small">(optional)</span></label>
        <input name="avatar" type="file" id="avatar" size="50" value="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
 {
?>
<div class="message">You must be a registered member to access this Page.<br />
<a href="connexion.php">Log in</a></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want the renamed image name to be uploaded to the "avatar" in db, and to a folder "avatar/users"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code of your form, the code of the page the form points to, the folder in which you want your pictures to be saved, how would you like your pictures to be renamed like and some info about your db table in which you want to save the new image name. Also keep in mind that you'll have to modify the views in order to display that uploaded profile picture somewhere

Comment: Please the comment box can contain my script

Comment: Edit your question, add the code there; space it out by 4 units so it will get highlighted as code.

Comment: ok thanks, i've done it, so i await your help sir

Comment: Somewhere if you register, it doesnt make sense to let people costumize their profile instantly. A person wants to register quickly. I do hope you made that profile pic optional :) Also it would be wiser to use `pdo` / `mysqli` functions, instead of the old depricated `mysql_` function if you are learning PHP. You skip the old path and take the quick route then ;)

Comment: yes the profile pic function is optional, it only shows in the edit profile form and not in the registration form